# Angular Interface for http request: JSON key not always same

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm making a request to an API that returns JSON, but the key is not always consistent, but I do know what it is going to be based off the input parameters. I am new on how the `Angular HttpClient` works. 
I am trying to set up an interface like this:

I have my function:

```
convert(amount: number, fromCurrency: string, targetCurrency: number): number
```

I'd like my interface to be like this:

```
interface UserResponse {
    fromCurrency + "_" + targetCurrency: string  

}
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I'm hoping my logic comes through on what I"m trying to achieve.

Edit: This is the API I am trying to use: 
https://www.currencyconverterapi.com/docs

Comment: this is not a good approach, i think the only reason you are going with approach is that you want to show `fromCurrency_targetCurrency` in your view. you can achieve this by sending one by one from api and then cancat in your view.

Comment: the `fromCurrency_targetCurrency` is how the JSON response is formatted. For Example `"USD_PHP" : 100`. From my understanding the name in the interface has to match what is returned in the JSON response?

Comment: yes you are right, name in the interface should match with json response.
but what i am saying is that you can send `UDS` and `PHP` as a seperate keys in json and then use in view as you want.
or you can set a generic key like `fromCurrecny_targetCurrency` without using concatenation operator.

Comment: right so since that changes depending on what my inputs were into the API I can't just hardcode something into the interface.

Comment: No, you can't achieve this in typescript in runtime. If u can't decide your key type,
you can use [key:string]:string  which called Index Signatures

Comment: Can you post in an answer, what you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You can't achieve your purpose during typescript runtime.

If you don't know what name of your object keys, you can use `Index Signatures`

This may not very closely related to your question. but it is an other way to

achieve "Dynamic key type"

For example

```
interface Foo {
  [key:string]: number
}

let foo: Foo = {x:1,y:2,..and what ever number type property};
```

Also you can define  all types first:

```
type Index = 'USD_PHP' | 'b' | 'c'
type FromIndex = { [k in Index]?: number }
```

You can learn more by looking at this [Typescript deep dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html)

Comment: I think I"m confused as to what you mean by not knowing the type of the key. The type is always a string, the issue is the actual name of the key. The API always returns a concatenation of the two inputs for the API with a "_" in between.

Comment: I'm looking at this code and read the doc, but am still confused as to what is going on. So we're saying with `[key:string] : number` that we don't know what the key is going to be named, but it's of some type string. And then right below we are explicitly putting all the possible names?

Comment: yes.  Your expectations are something like  "prefix_suffix",but it can't be achieved :(

Comment: Is there a way to just access the JSON api response as it is, and not have to deal with these interfaces? I don't remember having any of these issues in older versions of Angular,

Comment: You mean you use httpResponse Interceptors and don't want to define the response json data type? and by the way, you can use "any" in any way. for example : http_client.get<any>(...){}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183867/discussion-between-ecain-and-junk).